# express is not being found when running app

Tags: javascript

I am creating a web app with visual studio. I am trying to run node.js, and for some reason, I am getting an issue even though I did install typescript.

My code is this

```
var express=require('express');
var app=express();
var http=require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(http);
var ip = require('ip');
app.use(express.static('./')); 

require("./controller/controller.js")(app,io);

http.listen(8080,function(){
    console.log("Node Server is setup and it is listening on http://"+ip.address()+":8080");
})
```

and the error I get is:
Cannot find Module express.

I know that this might be a basic fix, but I am new to this, and don't know why its happening like this. any help would be appreciated

Comment: Add contents of your `package.json` in the question

Comment: npm install express http socket.io ip

Comment: Check if `express` is installed, if not, then run `npm i express` to install it...

Comment: try to do a quick read/search. here is a hello world explained example https://medium.com/@adnanrahic/hello-world-app-with-node-js-and-express-c1eb7cfa8a30